# java.math.BigInteger incompatible with java.lang.Long

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

```
private List getListByInsuredName(TxnListHelper listHelper) throws DAOException{
        Session session = null;
        session = getHibernateSession();
        String query = "SELECT txnRecNo From TxnInsured WHERE InsuredName LIKE :insuredname";
        Query getList = session.createSQLQuery(query);

        if(!GenericValidator.isBlankOrNull(listHelper.getInsuredName())){
            getList.setParameter("insuredname", "%" + listHelper.getInsuredName() + "%");   
        }

        List txnRecNoList = getList.list();
        return txnRecNoList;
    }

criteria.add(Restrictions.in("txnRecNo", getListByInsuredName(listHelper)));
```

txnRecNo is of bigint type field in database i want to add in criteria, and it is showing an exception **java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger incompatible with java.lang.Long**

Comment: You code is unclear. Where is the cast? What is Restrictions? Why do you use a Raw type List? Where is the StackTrace?

Answer (score 1):

BigInteger can hold an arbitrary amount of data. It can be way bigger than Long.MAX_VALUE.

To convert the value, use `txnRecNo.longValue()`